# Android App to print from a bluetooth printer

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid

The app I have found online works flawlessly except when clicking onto the Send Button, after typing something into the textbox, the printer runs, and stops in the middle of the process of printing, program doesn't crash however. I'm just curious if I'm using the wrong UUID, in fact I don't even know what it is. I have this following class, which is the only class needed to run the app, the rest are XML, with all three bluetooth permissions;

```
package com.example.bluetoothprinter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// will show the statuses
TextView myLabel;

// will enable user to enter any text to be printed
EditText myTextbox;

// android built in classes for bluetooth operations
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

OutputStream mmOutputStream;
InputStream mmInputStream;
Thread workerThread;

byte[] readBuffer;
int readBufferPosition;
int counter;
volatile boolean stopWorker;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {

        // we are goin to have three buttons for specific functions
        Button openButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.open);
        Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
        Button closeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.close);

        myLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label);
        myTextbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entry);

        // open bluetooth connection
        openButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    findBT();
                    openBT();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
        });

        // send data typed by the user to be printed
        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sendData();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
        });

        // close bluetooth connection
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    closeBT();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
        });

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/*
 * This will find a bluetooth printer device
 */
void findBT() {

    try {
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            myLabel.setText("No bluetooth adapter available");
        }

        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(
                    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
        }

        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter
                .getBondedDevices();
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {

                // OJL411MY29I911JH is the name of the bluetooth printer device shown after scan
                if (device.getName().equals("OJL411MY29I911JH")) {
                    mmDevice = device;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Device Found");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/*
 * Tries to open a connection to the bluetooth printer device
 */
void openBT() throws IOException {
    try {
        // Standard SerialPortService ID
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
        mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
        mmSocket.connect();
        mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
        mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();

        beginListenForData();

        myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Opened");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/*
 * After opening a connection to bluetooth printer device, 
 * we have to listen and check if a data were sent to be printed.
 */
void beginListenForData() {
    try {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        // This is the ASCII code for a newline character
        final byte delimiter = 10;

        stopWorker = false;
        readBufferPosition = 0;
        readBuffer = new byte[1024];

        workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()
                        && !stopWorker) {

                    try {

                        int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                        if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                            mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                            for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {
                                byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                if (b == delimiter) {
                                    byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                    System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0,
                                            encodedBytes, 0,
                                            encodedBytes.length);
                                    final String data = new String(
                                            encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                    readBufferPosition = 0;

                                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            myLabel.setText(data);
                                        }
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        stopWorker = true;
                    }

                }
            }
        });

        workerThread.start();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/*
 * This will send data to be printed by the bluetooth printer
 */
void sendData() throws IOException {
    try {

        // the text typed by the user
        String msg = myTextbox.getText().toString();
        msg += "\n";

        mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());

        // tell the user data were sent
        myLabel.setText("Data Sent");

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/*
 * Close the connection to bluetooth printer.
 */
void closeBT() throws IOException {
    try {
        stopWorker = true;
        mmOutputStream.close();
        mmInputStream.close();
        mmSocket.close();
        myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Closed");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your source code is from this step by step guide, please give some reference https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/03/android-bluetooth-tutorial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added code to run closeBT function at the end of the sendData function. if you don't close the connection, I think it is hanging in the process of sending.

```
void sendData() throws IOException {
try {

    // the text typed by the user
    String msg = myTextbox.getText().toString();
    msg += "\n";

    mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());

    // tell the user data were sent
    myLabel.setText("Data Sent");

}   catch (NullPointerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```